# login with smart card on web site

Tags: certificate, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I need help with sign in with a smart card on google chrome.

First: When I go to the page that requires the certificate, this window appears where you can choose the
certificate:
[select certificate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibSNb.png).
Is there any way this window can be edited so that I can see whose certificate is, and not just from whom it was issued, under the subject and the issuer is the same (from whom it was issued). I need to see here name of user.

Second: I have problem with loading certificates from smart cards on some computers. I installed software for smart card reader, insert smart card to reader, and windows doesn't load it. This is happening on some computers, all installed as it is on others, but does not want to load certificate. Certificates are all valid because this card work on other computer without problems

If there is someone who can help, it would be great. tnx

Answer (score 1):

> I need help with sign in with a smart card on google chrome

Your question is about *login with smart card on web site"* You can use a smartcard to prompt a certificate for authentication purposes during the handshake phase of the SSL/TLS protocol using client authentication, but you can not make digital signatures

Note: There is a workaround to do it, but this is a separate discussion: http://www.sslsignature.com/

> Is there any way this window can be edited so that I can see whose certificate is, and not just from whom it was issued, under the subject and the issuer is the same (from whom it was issued).

No, this window it is not customizable. You only can filter by issuer (stablishing in server side the accepted Certificate Authorities)

> I have problem with loading certificates from smart cards on some computers. I installed software for smart card reader, insert smart card to reader, and windows doesn't load it.

Check the installed drivers to fix it. I do not think it's a code problem

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use the certificate manager screen to aid in diagnosing your certificate propagation issue.
First: install the drivers for the smart card reader.
Second: Run 'services.msc'. Make sure the following services are started: Smart Card, Certificate Propagation.
Third: Run 'certmgr.msc'. Drill down to Personal->Certificate store, and insert the smart card. Hit F5 to refresh the certificate store. See if the certs from the card have been propagated to the personal cert store.

If this is working, then IE (and other browsers) should begin allowing smart card authentication for most smart cards.

For some special smart cards or features, you may need additional software installed in addition to the smart card reader driver.