# How to get authentication with USB Smart Card in Web browser using Angular

Tags: angular, certificate, usb, smartcard, usb-drive

I have a USB digital signatures(Smart Card). have any library can help me to call login form in this USB and getting result authentication invaild or vaild ?

Comment: You can't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750928/smartcard-reader-access-from-a-web-browser

Comment: You can not use a library to access USB but you could use SSL with client authentication https://stackoverflow.com/a/47030864/6371459

Comment: thank all i have solve that task, using application to get authentication

Comment: You may use Browser Extensions to support Digital Signing using Smartcard or use from modern browsers.  One such free browser extension provided by my Co. is Signer.Digital Chrome Extension.

Comment: Thank for your help ! I have found the way to do that, we can write an application to handle this work and Create URI to call application and wait application return

Comment: @ĐinhQuốcViệt Can you please share the answer. how you handled this ?